# Export tables from one to another SQL Server automatic batch job

Tags: sql-server

I have a local sql server, free version, for testing purposes and would like to automatically import data to it from a production server. 
I do it manually from SSMS - right click on *DB - Tasks - Export data...*, where I choose only the specific tables, but doing it a few times a day is a no go.

As the production DB is larger than the free version allows, I cannot simply backup the whole DB and load.
Neither can I make my local server a "linked" with the production, so simply

```
insert [server].[db].[schema].[table]
from [server].[db].[schema].[table]
```

won't work either.

I could not get `bcp`  command to execute without errors on some tables (`Error = [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0]Invalid character value for cast specification`):

```
bcp "select * from MyDB.dbo.Table where ID = 12345" QUERYOUT export.csv -w -t ; -k -T -S PRODSRV    
bcp MyDB.dbo.Table format nul -T -E -w -t ; -f format.fmt  -S PRODSRV
bcp MyLocalDB.dbo.Table IN export.csv  -k -T -S (localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB -f format.fmt
```

Thank you

Comment: You could save your SSIS-package (DB - Tasks - Export data) and then run it using some schedule

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Myro, you can use [SQL OpenRowSet](http://www.kodyaz.com/articles/how-to-sql-select-from-stored-procedure-using-openquery-openrowset.aspx) command to connect to a productive instance and import data from production database tables using SELECT and INSERT commands as follows

```
create table MyDBList ( dbname sysname)
GO

Insert into MyDBList (dbname)
SELECT rdb.name
FROM OPENROWSET('SQLNCLI', 'Server=kodyaz\sql2017;Trusted_Connection=yes;',
  'SELECT name FROM sys.databases') AS rdb
GO
```

This is very much like using a Linked Server but you don't need to create a database object in this case.

If your SQL Server configuration does not [allow Ad Hoc Distributed Queries](http://www.kodyaz.com/articles/enable-Ad-Hoc-Distributed-Queries.aspx), please try to set required configurations by executing following sp_configure command

```
sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1
reconfigure 

sp_configure 'Ad Hoc Distributed Queries', 1 
reconfigure 

sp_configure 'show advanced options', 0
reconfigure
```

Comment: Good idea, but this is not allowed on the server: Msg 15281, Level 16, SQL Server blocked access to STATEMENT 'OpenRowset/OpenDatasource' of component 'Ad Hoc Distributed Queries' because this component is turned off as part of the security configuration for this server. 
Could I allow it just for a specific user?

Comment: You need to change your server configuration options using sp_configure. I updated the answer.

Comment: Yes - the error is coming from your server install, not the production one